# Data Import Wizard - How to keep original SalesForce IDs of my records

Tags: administration, data-import-wizard

I am trying to import records of my custom objects using Data Import Wizard on a new account I just created.

For some reason, when adding new records, the data import process does not keep the original SalesForce IDs of the records and create new IDs instead. Doing so simply damages the import process since other master-details relations relies on such information.

Do you know how to solve this issue?

The main thing problem is when "Adding new records" the matching of SalesForce IDs is simply not available, although the data appears in the CSV file.
The funny thing is that in the "Example" column it appears well although the import process simply ignores it, very frustrating....

See image attached

[image]

Comment: That's because your `Id` field is not mapped in your import. should work fine when you map it.

Comment: The ID field is there, it can not be mapped when adding new records, only possible to map when records are updated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, SalesForce Data Import Wizard does not support import of the original SalesForce records IDs. To solve the issue of importing parent-child records you must import the parent records first then get the ids of the records of parent you imported and assign it to the child record (in your CSV)

My answer is taken out of SalesForce loading data guide [enter link description here](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01530000001x32RAAQ)

Comment: -1 this statement doesn't seems correct. While import of child object if you choose the map Id, it will upsert your matching records. Your question and answer contradicts as well, in question you're talking about importing child records and in answer its parent then child.